# WSO2 ESB EntitlementMediator can not send message to Identity Server

Tags: security, wso2, esb, identity

I am facing a problem in integrating WSO2 identity server with ESB.

After I followed the guide ["Using XACML Fine Grained Authorization with the WSO2 Product Platform"](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/10/using-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-wso2-platform/), I found that ESB had received message from client, but I didn't find that ESB had sent message to Identity Server.

I tried with `wso2esb-4.7.0` and `wso2is-4.1.0`

The following are the steps I took:

1. Configure the WSO2 Identity Server as the XACML engine and start Identity Server;
2. Configure the Entitlement mediator in the WSO2 ESB and start ESB;
3. Run the client code in the IDE.

In ESB and IS, there is no message outputted.

In the client IDE, the following messages occur in the console:

```
......

13/08/05 15:24:15 INFO deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: rahas - file:/D:/project/wso2/test/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/components/plugins/rampart-trust_1.6.1.wso2v8.jar
13/08/05 15:24:15 ERROR sandesha2.SandeshaModule: Could not load module policies. Using default values.
13/08/05 15:24:15 INFO tcp.TCPTransportSender: TCP Sender started
13/08/05 15:24:17 ERROR engine.AxisEngine: Missing wsse:Security header in request
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:356)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
    at org.wso2.entitlement.sample.WSEntitlementTestClient.main(WSEntitlementTestClient.java:59)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:141)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:356)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
    at org.wso2.entitlement.sample.WSEntitlementTestClient.main(WSEntitlementTestClient.java:59)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:141)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 11 more
```

The following is the client source code:

```java
package org.wso2.entitlement.sample;

import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace;
import org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder;
import org.apache.axis2.Constants;
import org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference;
import org.apache.axis2.client.Options;
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory;
import org.apache.neethi.Policy;
import org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine;
import org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData;

public class WSEntitlementTestClient {

 final static String ADDR_URL = "http://localhost:8280/services/echo"; //"http://localhost:8280/services/MarketDataService";
 final static String TRANS_URL =  "https://localhost:8243/services/EntitlementService"; // "https://localhost:8243/services/EntitlementProxy";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ServiceClient client = null;
  Options options = null;
  OMElement response = null;
  ConfigurationContext context = null;
  String trustStore = null;

  // You need to import the ESBs public certificate to this key store.
  trustStore = "wso2carbon.jks";
  // We are accessing ESB over HTTPS - so need to set trustStore parameters.
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
  // Password of mykeystore.jks
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");

  // Create configuration context - you will have Rampart module engaged in the client.axis2.xml
  context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("repo","repo/conf/axis2_client.xml");

  // This is the security policy of the proxy service applied UT.
  StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder("policy.xml");
  Policy policy = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(builder.getDocumentElement());

//    context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("repo","repo/conf/client.axis2.xml");
  client = new ServiceClient(context, null);
  options = new Options();
  options.setAction("urn:echoString");
  // This is the addressing URL pointing to the echo service deployed in ESB
  options.setTo(new EndpointReference(ADDR_URL));
  // To the ESB, the proxy service
  options.setUserName("admin");
  options.setPassword("admin");
  // TRANS_URL points to proxy service
  options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.TRANSPORT_URL, TRANS_URL);
  options.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY, policy);
  client.setOptions(options);
  client.engageModule("addressing");
  client.engageModule("rampart");
  response = client.sendReceive(getPayload("Hello world"));
  System.out.println(response);
 }

 private static OMElement getPayload(String value) {
  OMFactory factory = null;
  OMNamespace ns = null;
  OMElement elem = null;
  OMElement childElem = null;

  factory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
  ns = factory.createOMNamespace("http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org", "ns1");
  elem = factory.createOMElement("echoString", ns);
  childElem = factory.createOMElement("in", null);
  childElem.setText(value);
  elem.addChild(childElem);
  return elem;
 }
}
```

The following is the Entitlement Policy in the Identity Server:

```xml
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="Note" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
<Description>Note description    </Description>
<Target>
  <AnyOf>
     <AllOf>
        <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
           <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost:8280/services/echo</AttributeValue>
           <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
        </Match>
     </AllOf>
  </AnyOf>
</Target>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="primary-group-rule">
  <Target>
     <AnyOf>
        <AllOf>
           <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
           </Match>
        </AllOf>
     </AnyOf>
  </Target>
  <Condition>
     <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only">
           <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
        </Apply>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
     </Apply>
  </Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny-rule"/>
```

The following is the EntitlementService source in ESB:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="EntitlementService"
   transports="https"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <entitlementService remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9445/services/"
                         remoteServiceUserName="admin"
                         remoteServicePassword="enc:kuv2MubUUveMyv6GeHrXr9il59ajJIqUI4eoYHcgGKf/BBFOWn96NTjJQI+wYbWjKW6r79S7L7ZzgYeWx7DlGbff5X3pBN2Gh9yV0BHP1E93QtFqR7uTWi141Tr7V7ZwScwNqJbiNoV+vyLbsqKJE7T3nP8Ih9Y6omygbcLcHzg=">
        <onReject/>
        <onAccept/>
        <obligations/>
        <advice/>
     </entitlementService>
     <header name="wsse:Security" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
     <send/>
     <drop/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
     <drop/>
  </outSequence>
</target>
<enableSec/>
<policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/EntitlementService/services/EntitlementService/policies/UTOverTransport"/>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

In the ESB SOAP Message Tracer I can see the following Request Message:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
     <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-1">
           <wsu:Created>2013-08-05T06:10:20.503Z</wsu:Created>
           <wsu:Expires>2013-08-05T06:15:20.503Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
           <wsse:Username>aaa</wsse:Username>
           <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">admin</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
     <wsa:To>http://localhost:8280/services/echo</wsa:To>
     <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:269da889-ce33-4138-b050-3f4913dbbc17</wsa:MessageID>
     <wsa:Action>urn:echoString</wsa:Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <ns1:echoString xmlns:ns1="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
        <in>Hello world</in>
     </ns1:echoString>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

along with the following response:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <wsa:Action>urn:echoStringResponse</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:269da889-ce33-4138-b050-3f4913dbbc17</wsa:RelatesTo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:echoStringResponse xmlns:ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
     <return>Hello world</return>
  </ns:echoStringResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But in the Identity Server SOAP Message Tracer, the request message and response message are both empty. It seems like ESB does not send any message to the Identity Server.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At first WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 and WSO2 IS 4.1.0 are not the compatible versions. Either you can use ESB 4.6.0 with IS 4.1.0 or use WSO2 IS 4.5.0(which is to be released soon) with the current ESB.

This error you are facing 'Missing wsse:Security header in request' may be because of the BasicAuth scenario, that it first sends a request without user name and password, letting the server to submit the challenge. Only after receiving the challenge the client is sending the basicAuth parameters.

Cheers,

Pushpalanka

Comment: Could you please explain why or in what way they are not compatible? is it because ESB 4.7.0 is based on Carbon 4.1.X and IS 4.1.0 is based on Carbon 4.0.X? Or is there any other reason? How exactly can we tell version compatibility between different WSO2 products?

Comment: The scenarios will work with the latest packs of products. But when we are using different products based on different carbon kernel versions, there can be issues in feature installations.

Comment: Do you mean the above scenarios will successfully work by wso2esb-4.7.0 with wso2is-4.5.0?(I had tried it by wso2esb-4.6.0 with wso2is-4.1.0, it is not OK.)

Comment: The error you are getting is not due to the versions. It is just not sending the wsse headers, but trying to access a secured service. So it's a configuration error. I will try with your configuration and see what has gone wrong. If you can have a look look on the passing SOAP messages you will be able catch it.

Comment: I am very appreciated for you to try with my configuration, if you find anything wrong, please let me know. And I will have a look on the passing SOAP message too. Thank you very much!